# How to show My App icon in settings screen of my iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i am able to create sliders and switches for my app in settings screen but i want to create one setting like Push Notifications as shown in screen, that means when i select Push Notification it has to navigate to next view.

how can i do this using Settings.bundle.

[image]

can anyone give me the answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the settings bundle, use the Multi Value option. Add Titles and Values, that should be it.

Check out this link
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW14

Answer (score 1):

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW4.